# ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libmp3lame.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, heroku, ffmpeg

I am using  [this buildpack](https://github.com/arg0s/heroku-buildpack-python-ffmpeg-lame) (heroku-python-buildpack-ffmpeg-lame) for my app on heroku that uses ffmpeg to convert uploaded videos to .mp4. I had been using the version without libmp3lame, and since I switched I am getting the error

```
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libmp3lame.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked to see where libmp3lame.so.0 is located on my server with heroku run --app myapp find / -name libmp3lame.so.0, and the resulting path was /app/vendor/lame/lib/libmp3lame.so.0. I tried adding /vendor/lame/lib to my heroku path using the heroku config:set command, but even after adding it I still get the same error. Anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I stumbled across [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799636/why-changing-heroku-buildpack-for-existing-app-doesnt-run-bin-release), and I was able to see that all I needed to do was look at the bin/release file from the buildpack I was using and make sure the correct PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH were set to match the config_vars in that file. I set them using the heroku config:set command. Apparently the config_vars are only taken from the apps first deploy. Anyway, hope this will save someone else some time down the road.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem like this

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.so.0 /usr/lib64/libmp3lame.so.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on ubuntu 12.04 with ffmpeg - and not for heroku or similar. Just ffmpeg !

http://www.andyyardley.com/2009/03/02/ffmpeg-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libamrnbso3-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory